# Given a non-measurable set and a cardinal does there exist a subset of that cardinality which is measurable?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ not be Lebesgue-measurable. My questions then are:

1. If $\kappa\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ is any cardinal such that $\kappa>\aleph_0$ does there then exist a measurable subset $M$ of $A$ such that $\lvert M\rvert=\kappa$?
2. If the answer for (1) is negative: Since, $\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ how would the answer in (1) change if we only required $\kappa\leq \aleph_1$ (obviously still assuming $\kappa>\aleph_0$).
3. Where applicable, does assuming the Continuum Hypothesis affect any of the previous two questions?

Comment: If $\kappa \le \aleph_1$ and $\kappa > \aleph_0,$ then $\kappa = \aleph_1.$ It is consistent with ZFC that every subset of the reals with cardinality strictly less than $\mathfrak c$ is Lebesgue measurable (in particular has measure zero). It is also consistent with ZFC that there is a non-measurable set with cardinality $\mathfrak c$ that has no measurable subsets of cardinality $\mathfrak c$. (Both of these are implied by the continuum hypothesis, although the first one is trivial. But the first one also can hold nontrivially when CH is false.)

Comment: You might be interested in Sierpinski sets. These are uncountable sets of reals whose only measurable subsets are the countable ones.